# Ajax form - still cannot get it working with validation

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've posted on here previously, however, the answers received were of no help as they did not work.

I have a form that is using AJAX but the error or success messages don't appear.

Can anyone see what I may have overlooked? Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<form id="newsletter" action="http://app.bronto.com/public/webform/process/" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="gmy3v1ej883x2lffibqv869a2e3j9" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="37ea72cebcc05140e157208f6435c81b" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="delid" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="subid" value="" />
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            var fieldMaps = {};
                            </script>
                            <label for="nameField">Name:</label>
                            <input id="nameField" type="text" id="field_66663" name="39829[66663]" value="" />
                            <label for="emailField">Email:</label>
                            <input id="emailField" type="text" name="39821" value="" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            <div id="newsletter-message" style="display:none;"></div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
//ajax subscribe
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newsletter").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("submitting");
        alert(data); //it doesn't alert here??
        console.log($("#newsletter").serialize());
        $.post($("#newsletter").attr("action"), $("#newsletter").serialize(), function(data){
            alert(data); //doesn't alert here either
        if(data == 'success'){
        $('#newsletter-message').html('You have been signed up.').removeClass('error').css('visibility','visible');
            } else {
        $('#newsletter-message').html('Please complete the fields and re-submit').addClass('error').css('visibility','visible');
    }
        });
        //Stop the normal POST
        return false;
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

I've now tried this but still no luck..

```
$("#newsletter").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $( this ),
      ufname = $form.find( 'input[name="39829[66663]"]' ).val(),
      uemail = $form.find( 'input[name="39821"]' ).val(),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  var posting = $.post( url, { name: ufname, email: uemail } );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $('#newsletter-message').html('You have been signed up.').removeClass('error').css('visibility','visible');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thats because "data" is not defined !!

Comment: You never defined the `data` variable before you're alerting it. What is `data`?

Comment: `Data` should be the data post of email and name

Comment: Then you should define it. And see it it works. Thats as much as we can do.

Comment: Just trying to work out which vars they need to be defined as..

Comment: @woofmeow: Updated question with another attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The `visibility` and `display` are 2 different things in CSS.

You are creating your display `div` with `display:none;`, but then you try to make it visible with `.css('visibility','visible');`, so you just end up with:

```
<div style="display: none; visibility: visible;" id="newsletter-message">...</div>
```

Which is still not visible because of the `display:none;`.

You should replace the actions in your if by:

```
if(data == 'success'){
    $('#newsletter-message').html('You have been signed up.').removeClass('error').show();
} else {
    $('#newsletter-message').html('Please complete the fields and re-submit').addClass('error').show();
}
```

Here is the documentation about the `.show()` jQuery function: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

Small thing i noticed, you are using 2 `id` attribute for name field which makes your input invalid and may cause the problem.

```
<input id="nameField" type="text" id="field_66663" name="39829[66663]" value="" />
```

Also do as @Thierry said and avoid using numbers in name field if possible.